# Android NDK : Compiling different JNI Modules (jniLibs) for different architectures

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android.mk

I have Problem to compile different module having JNI library of different architectures

```
Module jniOne:
    /jniLib/armeabi
```

&

```
Module jniTwo: 
    /jniLib/armeabi-v7a
    /jniLib/x86
```

**Both Modules are different and having different .so files.**

Now the problem is when i include both module in Main Application One modules jni library not compiling and getting `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

```
MainApp: 
    build.gradle
    compile project(':jniOne')
    compile project(':jniTwo')
```

if i include any one from above two then apps running perfectly.

So what i am missing in this jniLib compilation?

Comment: What is your target architecture? If **jniOne** and **jniTwo** do not communicate, you can probably cheat and put the shared library(ies) of **jniOne** under **armeabi-v7a** (the ABIs are not compatible, but Java does not really care). Then, you will be able to install your APK on armeabi-v7a device or emulator. You can add **abiFilters** to your **build.gradle** remove the **x86** libraries.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge. All the modules having jniLibs in your projects should have same abiFilters jnilibs.

example:

Module jniOne:
    /jniLib/armeabi

Module jniTwo: 
    /jniLib/armeabi

In your case the problem is jniOne creates armeabi and jniTwo creates armeabi-v7a, x86. At runtime system try to link 'so' files from all created folders. where it cant find JniTwo 'so' files in armeabi and JniOne 'so' files in armeabi-v7a, x86 and gives UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Also add:

ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', ....
        }
    in defaultConfig of your project and modules gradles.